# Garbled text when printing website

Tags: css, printing, fonts

I'm working on a website where the users will be printing pages from the site fairly frequently, in order to give them to people without internet access. Some of the text comes out garbled when printed on our users' office printers:

[image: Garbled text on printout]

That's supposed to say **Reduced Fare and Free Ride Programs, Chicago Transit Authority**.

My first thought was that this has something to do with the font we're using, so I changed that text to have `font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif`. Some google research made me think those font settings were widely supported and shouldn't cause problems, but our users are still having the issue.

Even if you don't know exactly how to fix this problem, I would appreciate suggestions about

1. What other than the font selection could be causing it?
2. If you do think it has something to do with the font, what is a good font to use? Or how could I figure that out, is it printer-specific?

### Update

The page is being printed from the browser, which for this particular group of users is IE8. I'm not sure what version of Windows they're on. I've tested this on a Windows machine with IE8 in our office, and was not able to reproduce the issue. So while the browser might be a factor, I don't believe it's the only factor.

### Second Update

The font we're using is [Libre Baskerville](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Libre+Baskerville), which we're loading through the Google Fonts API. It renders fine on screen, and actually prints with no issue from some of the printers at our client's office. The text only comes out garbled when printed on a [Lexmark MS410dn](http://www.lexmark.com/US/en/view/US-Printers%20&%20MultiFunction/Lexmark-MS410dn/catId=cat170005-category&prodId=7695-product).

Comment: What are you using to print the web page? Are you printing it from the browser (which browser?) or are you generating a PDF on the server side, or are you using some sort of HTML5 canvas on the client side to draw it?

Comment: Some printers have font rendering engines in them, but most print jobs embed the fonts so I doubt your office printer is what's causing the issue. An easy way to test would be to print a different webpage that uses the same font. If the page prints correctly, then you know it's not a hardware issue. For us to really help though, it would be useful to see the code you're using, otherwise all we can do is speculate.

Comment: Also, are your users printing from Macs or PCs? Macs don't (by default) have Times New Roman, but a similar font called just "Times". You could try something like `font-family: TimesNewRoman, 'Times New Roman', Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;` which may help the issue.

Comment: And one more thought that just crossed my mind, you can also try using `@font-face` to embed the fonts, and bypass any issues with your users not having them installed. You could even use a separate "print" style sheet and embed SVG fonts. SVG fonts are actually just vector outlines, rather than actual fonts, so any hardware issues should be circumvented.

Comment: Thanks for the initial feedback, I posted some updates above. Is there any particular section of code that you would like to see?

Comment: We are using a `@font-face` declaration, and loading the font from [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Libre+Baskerville). Web fonts are definitely not my area of expertise... is this using SVG?

Answer (score 3):

I saw these same types of printing errors. I created a PDF in Indesign on Windows 10 using the Libre Baskerville font. When I tried to print the PDF on OSX using Preview I got the same garbled glyphs seen above. I fixed it by uninstalling the Libre Baskerville fonts which were Truetype format and installing Libre Baskerville fonts in Opentype format and resetting the fonts in the document. It seemed to work.

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Many thanks. This worked for me too. The only problem is that the .otf looks rubbish on the screen, although it prints out beautifully. I found another solution too. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the simplest solution was to use a different font for printing. The issue only happened with the Libre Baskerville font on a few specific printers, so in our `print.css` stylesheet we just use a basic serif font instead. Not ideal, but at least the printouts are legible.

In the original post I said that I had tried switching the font in the printouts and users were still having problems. This turned out to be due to caching of the `print.css` stylesheet, so that fix actually did solve the problem.

In the long term we'll probably find a font that works consistently on all their printers and switch the website over to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the record (and anyone reading this with a similar issue), I had exactly the same issue trying to print a document written in Libre Baskerville on my laptop, in LibreOffice.  The font is embedded in both RTF and PDF formats and the text is garbled in the same way.  I also worked around the issue by changing to a different font.  It's a pity as LibreBaskerville is a nice font.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the True Type version of the font with the Open Type version - I am now able to print Libre Baskerville with no issues.  The Open Type version is not easy to find as most downloads (including Google Fonts) only give you the option of a .ttf file. Search for a .otf file version - I found one here: https://www.broble.com/download-free-font/libre-baskerville

Comment: Thanks! I don't work on this system anymore and don't have anyway to test out this suggestion, but hopefully it'll be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the imported font files have some errors in them. Sometimes, if you use a online font to webfont converter it makes some mistakes with the conversion. You could try [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts). Find a serif font that you like and use their files and import scripts.

For example, if you want to use the font Bitter:

1. Just put `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter);` at the top of your CSS file
2. Use `font-family: 'Bitter', serif;` in your style declarations.

NB: The `serif` part is a fallback in case something goes wrong, then the clients browser chooses the default serif font instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We're already using Google Fonts, with the Libre Baskerville font. Since it renders fine on screen and from most printers I'm skeptical that the imported font file has an error in it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to print using a PCL rather than a PS driver. That way I get proper printing and the font also looks good on screen.

@Gerard's method of using .otf files rather than .ttf ones enables proper printing too, but it has the drawback of not showing the text so nicely on the screen.